# Date Format from JavaScript into MySQL Date type

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, date, getdate

I can't figure out how to convert the date from this format: `Tue Feb 06 2018 19:41:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` into a format that would be accepted by MySQL DATE type.

I can convert the date with this approach in JavaScript:

```
var day = Date.getDate();
var month = Date.getMonth() +1;
var year = Date.getFullYear();
var DateInMySqlFormat = year + '-' + '0' + month + '-' + day;
```

This will work fine. But is there any way that I can convert the date `Tue Feb 06 2018 19:41:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` on the server side with PHP? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = 'Tue Feb 06 2018 19:41:58 GMT-0500';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code.

Comment: What part are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: I understand your code but I just suggest you to improve your answer by just adding some description not just provide only code. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You can send the `DateInMySqlFormat` to the backend and then you can create a `DateTime` object from `createFromFormat` method, which then can be manipulated with `format` method to change the format to some other. Available formats from official docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2018-02-11');
echo $date->format('Y/m/d'); //2018/02/11
echo $date->format('Y-M-d'); //2018-Jan-11
```